# How to find a list of files that are of specific extension but do not contain certain characters in their file name?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a folder with files that have extensions, such as `.txt`, `.sh` and `.out`.

However, I want a list of files that have only `.txt` extension, **with** the file names not containing certain characters.

For example, the `.txt` files are named `L-003_45.txt` and so on all up to `L-003_70.txt`. Some files have a change in the `L-003` part to lets say `L-004`, creating duplicates of lets say file 45, so basically both `L-003_45.txt` and `L-004_45.txt` exist. So I want to get a list of text files that don't have 45 in their name.

How would I do that?

I tried with `find` and `ls` and succeeded but I would like to know how to do a `for loop` instead.

I tried:
`for FILE in *.txt; do ls -I '*45.txt'; done` but it failed.

Would be grateful for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you use Bash's `ext`ended`glob`ing

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Enables extended globing
shopt -s extglob

# Prevents iterating patterns if no match found
shopt -s nullglob

# Iterates files not having 45 or 57 before .txt
for file in !(*@(45|57)).txt; do
  printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

Comment: This one works great! But what about if similarly like 45, I have 57 and want to exclude both at the same time?

Comment: @Liviosah `for file in !(*@(45 57)).txt; do` excludes both 45 and 57.

Comment: @Liviosah Sorry, this is the correct one: `for file in !(*@(45|57)).txt; do` excludes both 45 and 57.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use the `find` command to find all files with the required extensions, and later filter out the ones with the "strange" characters, e.g. for finding the file extensions:

```
find ./ -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.sh" -o name "*.out"
```

... and now, for not showing the ones with "45" in the name, you can do:

```
find ./ -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.sh" -o name "*.out" | grep -v "45"
```

... and if you don't want "45" nor "56", you can do:

```
find ./ -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.sh" -o name "*.out" | grep -v "45" | grep -v "56"
```

Explanation:

- `-o` stands for `OR`
- `grep -v` stands for "--in**v**ert-match" (not showing those results)

Comment: Oh: in case you only want to check your current directory, you can add `-maxdepth 1` to your `find` command.

Answer (score 1):

Setup:

```
$ touch L-004_23.txt L-003_45.txt L-004_45.txt L-003_70.txt

$ ls -1 L*txt
L-003_45.txt
L-003_70.txt
L-004_23.txt
L-004_45.txt
```

One idea using `!` to negate a criteria:

```
$ find . -name "*.txt" ! -name "*_45.txt"
./L-003_70.txt
./L-004_23.txt
```

Feeding the `find` results to a `while` loop, eg:

```
while read -r file
do
    echo "file: ${file}"
done < <(find . -name "*.txt" ! -name "*_45.txt")
```

This generates:

```
file: ./L-003_70.txt
file: ./L-004_23.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution with `extglob` is a very good one. In case you need to exclude more than one pattern you can also test and continue. Example to exclude all `*45.txt` and `*57.txt`:

```sh
declare -a excludes=("45" "57")
for f in *.txt; do
  for e in "${excludes[@]}"; do
    [[ "$f" == *"$e.txt" ]] && continue 2
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$f"
done
```